# Why does Python defaultdict use factory method pattern?

Tags: python, dictionary

Python has a [`defaultdict` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which behaves like a dictionary, except that it outputs a default value when encountering a new key. This default value is created using the `default_factory` attribute, which is a function that takes no arguments.

For example, `d = defaultdict(int)` creates a dictionary `d` whose default value is 0, since `int()` returns 0.

Why is the default value stored as a function which takes no arguments, rather than storing the default value itself? I am assuming there is a reason behind this choice of implementation, but I don't see what it is. From a naive perspective, it seems like storing the default value would be just as effective and less convoluted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think about how this would work for mutable types.

For example, `d = defaultdict(list)` creates a new list object for each unassigned key that is requested. If you used a single instance, then each key would be returning the same instance of that list. Appending to an instance returned by one key, e.g. `d[1].append(2)` would have the observable behavior of appending the value to every other key in the dict. That behavior in almost all cases would be undesirable.

Yes, for primitive/immutable datatypes, like `int`, `float`, `str`, etc, a default value would be acceptable, but that does not cover a huge use-case for containers or other mutable structures where you would want the value for each key to be unique.